# Syncfusion SfDataGrid Change foreground of cell based on value

Tags: c#, wpf, converters, syncfusion, sfdatagrid

I am attempting to change the foreground of a cell based on the DateTime value from an object in the ItemsSource using a converter.

The issue that I am having is that when running the application I get an exception of 'GridCell' TargetType does not match type of element 'GridCell'.

The exception doesn't seem to make any sense since a GridCell TargetType is exactly the same as a GridCell element. I would greatly appreciate it if someone could point out what I am doing wrong. The code is below.

Model used in generating the ItemsSource (code behind creates a List. This all works fine)

```
﻿﻿public class RelationalTable 
{
    public int ClaimNumber { get; set; }
    public DateTime PlanPosted { get; set; }
    public DateTime PlanDue { get; set; }
    public int PlanVersion { get; set; }
    public string Department { get; set; }
}
```

SfDataGrid markup:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
<!-- converter is defined in the UserControl header xmlns:converter=<assembly holding the converter code> -->
    <converter:StyleConverterByDate x:Key="ConverterResult" />
</UserControl.Resources>

        <sf:SfDataGrid x:Name="SfGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding ClaimList}" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                       IsReadOnly="True" AllowSorting="True" AllowFiltering="True"
                       FontFamily="{StaticResource AppFont}"
                       AllowEditing="False" AllowTriStateSorting="True" ColumnSizer="AutoWithLastColumnFill"
                       RowHeight="32">

            <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                <loc:SfDataGridBehavior />
            </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <sf:SfDataGrid.Columns>
                <sf:GridTextColumn HeaderText="Claim Number"
                                   HorizontalHeaderContentAlignment="Left"
                                   MappingName="ClaimNumber">
                </sf:GridTextColumn>
                <sf:GridDateTimeColumn CustomPattern="MM/dd/yyyy"
                                       HorizontalHeaderContentAlignment="Left"
                                       HeaderText="Date Posted"
                                       MappingName="PlanPosted"
                                       Pattern="CustomPattern" />
                <sf:GridDateTimeColumn CustomPattern="MM/dd/yyyy"
                                       HorizontalHeaderContentAlignment="Left"
                                       HeaderText="Date Due"
                                       MappingName="PlanDue"
                                       Pattern="CustomPattern">


                    <sf:GridDateTimeColumn.CellStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="sf:GridCell">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{Binding PlanDue, Converter={StaticResource ConverterResult}}" />
                        </Style>
                    </sf:GridDateTimeColumn.CellStyle>



                </sf:GridDateTimeColumn>
                    
                <sf:GridTextColumn HeaderText="Department"
                                   HorizontalHeaderContentAlignment="Left"
                                   MappingName="Department" />

            </sf:SfDataGrid.Columns>
        </sf:SfDataGrid>
```

And finally the converter

```
public class StyleConverterByDate : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        DateTime _value = (DateTime)value;
        DateTime _today = DateTime.Today;

        if (_value.Date >= _today.Date)
            return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
  
        if (_value.Date > _today.Date.AddDays(-10) && _value.Date < _today.Date)
            return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Yellow);

        return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution. I replaced the CellStyle with a CellTemplate and used a TextBlock inside a DataTemplate to display the cell data.

```
<sf:GridDateTimeColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding PlanDue, StringFormat=MM/dd/yyyy}"
                   Foreground="{Binding PlanDue, Converter={StaticResource StyleConverter}}"
                   VerticalAlignment="Center"
                   FontFamily="{StaticResource AppFont}"
                   FontWeight="DemiBold"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</sf:GridDateTimeColumn.CellTemplate>
```

The foreground color of the Date in the GridDateTimeColumn now changes at runtime based on the condition met in the converter.

Hope this helps someone else because I was stumped for a while on this one.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that your reported exception is arising because there is a conflict with the "GridCell" class existing in both *Syncfusion.SfGrid.WPF* and *Syncfusion.Grid.WPF* DLLs.

This conflict results in an exception where the Style Property ‘Foreground’ cannot be found in the type reference when you reference http://schemas.Syncfusion.com/wpf in your project.

To fix this issue, you can explicitly declare the namespace for "GridCell" by specifying the assembly in the following way:

xmlns:sfdatagrid="clr-namespace:Syncfusion.UI.Xaml.Grid;assembly=Syncfusion.SfGrid.WPF"

Code snippet :

<UserControl x:Class="SfDataGrid_Demo.MyUserControl"

```
         xmlns=http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation

         xmlns:x=http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml

         xmlns:mc=http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006

         xmlns:d=http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008

         xmlns:syncfusion=http://schemas.syncfusion.com/wpf

         xmlns:sfdatagrid="clr-namespace:Syncfusion.UI.Xaml.Grid;assembly=Syncfusion.SfGrid.WPF"

         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SfDataGrid_Demo"

         mc:Ignorable="d"

         d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">

<UserControl.DataContext>

    <local:ViewModel/>

</UserControl.DataContext>

<UserControl.Resources>

    <local:StyleConverterByDate x:Key="ConverterResult"/>

</UserControl.Resources>



<Grid x:Name="Root_Grid">

    <Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>

        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>

   </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <syncfusion:SfDataGrid x:Name="dataGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding Orders}" AllowSorting="True"  SelectionMode="Extended" AllowEditing="True" AllowTriStateSor

        <syncfusion:SfDataGrid.Columns>

            <syncfusion:GridDateTimeColumn CustomPattern="MM/dd/yyyy"

                                 HorizontalHeaderContentAlignment="Left"

                                 HeaderText="Date Due"

                                 MappingName="Date"

                                 Pattern="CustomPattern">

                <syncfusion:GridDateTimeColumn.CellStyle>

                    <Style TargetType="sfdatagrid:GridCell">

                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{Binding Date, Converter={StaticResource ConverterResult}}" />

                    </Style>

                </syncfusion:GridDateTimeColumn.CellStyle>

            </syncfusion:GridDateTimeColumn>

        </syncfusion:SfDataGrid.Columns>

    </syncfusion:SfDataGrid>

</Grid>
```

For more information related to ambiguous type reference exceptions, please refer to the below knowledge base documentation link,

KB Link:  https://www.syncfusion.com/kb/5712/how-to-resolve-ambiguous-type-reference-exception